Reloaded problem of selenium when scraping video metadata from YouTube
When I used selenium to scrape YouTube video metadata dynamically, I'd always encountered a problem that whenever the RELOADED screen showed up, my script just couldn't run anymore, unless I manually refresh the webpage again.
I've tried to set up a check web status function that if the web doesn't send back the web status, it will break the while loop and close the driver at the same time.
I expected to see when the RELOADED web page shows up, which represents that the web cannot send a normal status back to my part and the check status function can automatically close the driver.
My code is demonstrated as follows:
# check staus function
def check_status(driver, timeout=5):
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < timeout:
        try:
            status_code = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0].responseStatus;")
            if status_code == 200:
                print("Satus True")
                return True
            else:
                print("Status Error")
                return False
        except Exception:
            # 如果出現異常，繼續嘗試
            pass
    
    # 如果超時，返回 False
    print("Overtime")
    return False

# YouTube crawler
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("YOUR COOKIE")
options.add_argument("--incognito") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(8)

scroll_times = 1
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")


while True:
    try:
        # check web status
        print("start")
        if check_status(driver=driver):
            print("checking")
            print(f"Web page HTTP status code: 200")
        else:
            print("Status changed!")
            driver.quit()
            break

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight)")
        sleep = randint(6, 8)
        time.sleep(sleep)
        
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
        if new_height == last_height:
            print("No more spaces!")
            break
        last_height = new_height
        print(f"The {scroll_times} times!")
        scroll_times += 1
        data = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;") # get HTML tags
        time.sleep(2)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        driver.quit()

### Deal with HTML stuff ###
driver.quit()
root= bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser') 
main_titles = root.find_all("yt-formatted-string", class_="style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media")
partial_links = root.find_all("a", class_="yt-simple-endpoint focus-on-expand style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media")
meta_data = root.find_all("span", class_="inline-metadata-item style-scope ytd-video-meta-block")

view_counts = []
upload_times = []
for i in range(0, len(meta_data), 2):
    view_counts.append(meta_data[i].text)
    upload_times.append(meta_data[i + 1].text)

view_times_list = [re.sub("View times：", "", view) for view in view_counts]
title_list_clean = [title.text for title in main_titles]
title_list_clean = [title for title in title_list_clean if len(title) !=0]

main_links_list = []
for link in partial_links:
    short_link = link["href"]
    full_short_link = "https://www.youtube.com/" + short_link
    main_links_list.append(full_short_link)

Result
The 74 times!
start
Satus True
checking
Web page HTTP status code: 200
The 75 times!
start
Satus True
checking
Web page HTTP status code: 200
The 76 times!
Note
When it ran to 76 times, my code just not worked anymore from here. You can see I had three checking points (start, Status True, checking) each time. However, when it bumped into 76 times, checking points disappered, representing that the code DID NOT actually run anything. But, when I closed the pop-out selenium window,  my code started working and I could collect the desired data. I want to understand how to keep my code from disrupting by the RELOADED web page and I have no need to close the window MANUALLY.
